# MYSQL Checking even/odd within a substring

Tags: mysql

I have a query where one condition to check if a room number is odd/even. The issue is that the room number is stored with the building info as well in a string.

Here is the format of the data in the database:

```
ABC-0101A  (Odd)
ABC-0112B  (Even)
ZYX-123A1  (Odd)
ZYX-456B1  (Even)
```

For a room number to be considered even/odd, it is dependent on the last number before the first letter after the dash.

Comment: The data is stored in a variable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be quite a lot easier and more performant if you could separately store the numeric portion in another column. As a long term solution, I would recommend doing that.

But you can use a regular expression here to match the last digit before the first number, with a set of even `[02468]` and a set of odd `[13579]` with a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN room REGEXP '-[0-9]*[02468][A-Z]' THEN 'even'
    WHEN room REGEXP '-[0-9]*[13579][A-Z]' THEN 'odd'
    ELSE 'something else entirely'
  END
FROM rooms
```

The pattern `-[0-9]*` matches a literal hyphen followed by zero or more digits. Then the significant part is the `[02468]` or `[13579]` set to match an even or odd digit that must be present immediately preceding `[A-Z]` matching the next letter.

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/464d1d/3

Exmaple matching an even room:

```
SELECT 'ABC-0112B' REGEXP '-[0-9]*[02468][A-Z]';
+------------------------------------------+
| 'ABC-0112B' REGEXP '-[0-9]*[02468][A-Z]' |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        1 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Example matching an odd room:

```
SELECT 'ABC-0101A' REGEXP '-[0-9]*[13579][A-Z]';
+------------------------------------------+
| 'ABC-0101A' REGEXP '-[0-9]*[13579][A-Z]' |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        1 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Example matching an odd room that doesn't end with a letter:

```
SELECT 'ABC-0101A11' REGEXP '-[0-9]*[13579][A-Z]';
+--------------------------------------------+
| 'ABC-0101A11' REGEXP '-[0-9]*[13579][A-Z]' |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: not all room numbers end alphabetically, though. it should be more like `/[02468][A-Z]?$/`, basically

Comment: @MarcB It doesn't need to match the whole pattern, just the center portion with the digit that's important.  There's no `$` anchor.

Comment: ah yes. true 'nuff. 'first letter after the dash'.

Comment: Thanks I agree the data should've been split. Unfortunately now is not an easy time to do that but it is planned for the future!

Comment: @James Glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First create a function IsNumeric which returns 1 if number is integer otherwise 0:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (input varchar(1024)) RETURNS int
RETURN input REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';
```

Then use following query to check room number:

```
select IF (IsNumeric(right(room,1))>0, 
        IF(right(room,1)%2=0,'Even','ODD'),
        IF(left(right(room,2),1)%2=0,'Even','ODD')
      ) as room_number
from rooms;
```

Here in above query first check if last digit is integer, If so then check for even/Odd number. If digit is not integer pick the 2nd last digit and apply the same check.